# Неявное преобразования между Complex и double,вызов метода

Tags: c#

Прежде всего ещё раз благодарность пользователю nuts119 за огромную помощь .

А теперь собственно к задаче.Есть формула нахождения плотности

```
static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double U, double frequency, double T)
{
    NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
    double real = U * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Cos(-frequency * x), 0, T);
    double imaginary = U * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Sin(-frequency * x), 0, T);
    return new Complex(real, imaginary);
}
```

На основе полученного значения формулы выше, нужно найти уже следующие значения,и в формате комплексных чисел.
Применяется формула Эйлера

```
static Complex GetNewVal(double U, double frequency, double T)
{
    NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
    double part1 = U / GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T) * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Cos(-frequency * x), 0, T);
    double part2 = U / GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T) * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Sin(-frequency * x), 0, T);
    return new Complex(part1,part2);
}
```

Конечно на строки part1,part2 он ругается так как неявное преобразование между System.Numerics.Complex и double невозможно.
Вопрос заключается в следующем

Какие способы возможны для преобразования между System.Numerics.Complex и double?

Знаю, что с величинами проблему можно решить с помощь explicit-преобразования.
Но здесь немного другое,здесь происходит вызов метода,для получения новых значений,то есть значение уже есть и оно вызывается через метод и используется для решения по новой формуле.
Вся формула представлена на рисунке ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод static Complex GetNewVal(double U,double frequency,double T) нахожу по этой формуле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос про перевод комплексных в реальные кажется странным. Ну, то есть, можно взять действительную часть, или радиус, но зачем? По-моему, у вас что-то не так с методом расчета.

Comment: а по какой формуле строилась функция `static Complex GetNewVal(double U, double frequency, double T)` ?

Comment: Поймите, сейчас у вас написана вот такая формула: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0tiz.png

Comment: Она неправильная и вообще сокращается в 1. В приведенной вами формуле нет никакого деления на интеграл - но вы почему-то упорно отстаиваете необходимость деления на `GetSpectralDensity`

Comment: Я настаивал потому что мне казалось что на основе полученного значения GetSpectralDensity я должен ещё что-то получить,чтобы дойти к главной цели(построения частотного и спектрального графика)
Отсюда и моё упорство

Взял за основу вашу подсказку

static Complex GetNewVal(double U, double frequency, double T)
        {
            NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();       
            var arg1 = frequency * T;
            return U / (-Complex.ImaginaryOne * frequency) * Complex.Exp(-Complex.ImaginaryOne * arg1);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы как-то странно подошли к задаче: ваш код не соответствует вашей же формуле. Если у вас есть dот такая формула -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то и писать программу надо так же.

```
static Complex Foo (double U, double ω, double τ) {
  var arg = ω * τ / 2;
  return U * τ * Math.Sin(arg) / arg * Complex.Exp( - Complex.ImaginaryOne * arg );
}
```

Если вспомнить формулу Эйлера, то можно записать проще:

```
static Complex Foo (double U, double ω, double τ) {
  var arg = ω * τ / 2;
  return Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(U * τ * Math.Sin(arg) / arg, -arg );
}
```

Но, в любом случае, тут нет никакого интегрирования!

Comment: Пока я работаю с 2-ой формулой,где синус формулу не трогал.

А там интегрирование есть.

Comment: @beginner где оно там есть?

Comment: @beginner вертикальная черта - это разность значений функции в двух точках, а не интегрирование.

Comment: Это исправимо
Здесь стоит другая важная пробема.

Какие способы возможны для преобразования между System.Numerics.Complex и double?

Потому что метод возвращает Complex,потом его надо вызвать в другом методе,в моём случае это static Complex GetNewVal(double U, double frequency, double T)

Там я вызываю static Complex GetSpectralDensity и компилятор говорит что невозможно преобразовать из комплекса в double,оно и понятно,но есть же способы.

explicit чисто для величин,но не для методов

Comment: @beginner значит, вы неправильно записали формулу. Если формулу записать правильно - вам такое преобразование не понадобится.